SageMaker Studio for Classroom Exercises - Estimating the Cost/Instance(s) for Simultaneous Users
I'm estimating the costs for building a classroom training environment in AWS SageMaker Studio. The class will be in-person / real-time with 20 participants working on code exercises in Notebooks. The class will touch on topics in TensorFlow and MLFlow, so I'm assuming for the TF part I'll want to make sure GPU(s) are available.
How do I estimate the instance size I would need for simultaneous users in SageMaker Studio? My concern is that if 20 participants are concurrently executing code in, say, 20 separate Notebooks, that the instance could bottleneck or even crash.
I cannot seem to find anything in the AWS documentation that explicitly states how to estimate resources for concurrent users in Studio -- are all users utilizing the same underlying instance? Is each user given their own separate instance?

According to the SageMaker document, you can use "Space" to share/separate instances.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-updated-spaces.html

Spaces are used to manage the storage and resource needs of some Amazon SageMaker Studio applications. Each space has a 1:1 relationship with an instance of an application.

About how many participants can share a same instance, it depends on the workload's memory usage and required number of GPUs, vs instance type/size.
